# jGrasp compile and link issue

Tags: object, compilation, mingw, exe, jgrasp

I am using jGrasp on Windows 10 to write in C and can't compile anything. MinGW is the compiler I have downloaded. Using code which I have successfully compiled on previous machines (Win 7), I am experiencing the same issue each time. The 'compile and link' command results in a '.o' file instead of a '.exe' file. I can't find anything about it, other than '.o' means 'object' file. Any potential solutions or leads? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't figured this out yet, turn on "Settings" > "Verbose" messages, then check the output after a compile-and-link for "Actual Command Sent". Is the command what you expect it to be?

Comment: Thank you. I did that, and got this output: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file test.exe: Permission denied
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Do you have write permissions on the directory where the executable would go? What happens if you try the same compile command from the console?

If you don't get this figured out, use "Help" > "Report a Bug" to send a bug report. Include your email and enough information so I'll know it's you.

Comment: I have no idea what happened, because I gave up trying to fix it. I opened it recently to have another crack at solving it, and there are no issues to be found. No idea what happened. Thank you for your help though!